# Teradata result set returns smallest length for columns

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a query that returns data but it returns the shortest length name from the column in the table, in the result set. I want the full length returned of all fields from the column. I have not been able to find a reason for this. Using Teradata and Teradata SQL Assistant 15.10.1.4.

I have looked here and googled it. Not finding anything similar for result set coming back with shortest length for all fields.

```
SELECT ELEMENT_NAME, COUNT(*) AS IdCount
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY ELEMENT_NAME
ORDER BY ELEMENT_NAME;
```

I would expect this output. Code works fine. It is the output that does not.

```
ELEMENT_NAME  IdCount
ABC_DEF       100
GHI           200
```

What I am getting:

```
ELEMENT_NAME IdCount
ABC          100
GHI          200
```

Comment: Is there a union in your real query?

Comment: Or does the real query reference a view that includes a UNION?

Comment: No Union. Basically this is the query. Why it only returns the shortest name in result set is odd to me. I was thinking it is a setting in SQL Assistant but have not seen anything there to say that is it either.

Comment: Try `SELECT char_length(ELEMENT_NAME), COUNT(*) AS IdCount FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY 1 order by 1 desc` to check the actual lengths. Can you show the definition of this `ELEMENT_NAME` column?

Comment: It puts a 3 in there now. So it is saying it is only 3 characters long? Why would that be when 1 table has it 7 characters long.

Comment: I have figured out why it is doing it. For some reason when importing the data into a single table it truncated all the data. Not sure why this happened. Thanks for the help. Using char_length made me look at the data again and noticed why now. Thanks for the  help.